# xcode 4 debugging shows 'Summary Unavailable' for most objects

Tags: iphone, xcode

Whilst using Xcode 4.0 and trying to debug and see what value is held in what variable - or see what objects are in an array etc,  I always seem to get "Summary Unavailable" or "Invalid Summary".

The problem seems much like the one in 3.2.6 if you built and ran a release version with the symbols stripped.

Any chance that any one knows where I am going wrong, or what the resolution is 
For years things worked smoothly - then Apple stepped in - again.

Thanks

Comment: While running an application on a device with an iOS version 4.3 or earlier, you might not be able to see formatted content of variables and a “/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found)“ message is shown in the gdb console window. You can use the 'po' command in gdb console to get around the issue. -> as per apples release notes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not going wrong, Xcode 4 is. This problem is pretty common, unfortunately. Report it at http://bugreport.apple.com/ and hope for the best.

In the meantime you can inspect variables using the console, which appears at the bottom of Xcode 4's window during debugging. If you have an object "myObj", you can inspect it in the console by typing "po myObj". It's a lot less convenient but it's better than not getting the information at all.

Comment: ok thanks alot, would you suggest its a good move to go back to previous version of Xcode or keep stabbing away at 4.0?

Comment: I'm using 4 for most things, but I've found it necessary to keep 3 around for certain uses. Xcode 4 seems to have some significant problems in its Core Data model editor, for example, and frequently beachballs when I attempt to use it. I'm sticking with 4 as much as possible though, because I'm confident the bugs will be fixed. Xcode 3 has its own set of bugs, so it's more trading one set for another than choosing between buggy or stable.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try changing the "Summary Format" in the GDB window. Try something like {(NSString *)[$VAR description]}:s as the Summary format - this works for NSManagedObject derived objects.

Comment: in my case i had this exact string as summary format, i did set it maybe a year ago. Now, in xcode 7, i couldn't see any value debugging swift code, until i saw this again and *removed* this custom string! So i would say don't do this anymore, today it makes more problems than it solves

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for Apple to fix Xcode 4 you can try using "Print Description", which prints the value to console.

Answer (score 2):

Start your app up in debug

IN XCODE 4.02, go to Product/Debug/Shared Libraries

The window that appears tells you which dynamicLibs are loaded

Scroll down until you see "libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib
Click the "Load" button, and then "Done"

After stopping on a breakpoint, the contents of a string should be printed in blue after the object's address.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That library doesn't appear in the list here using XCode 4.0 build 4A304a

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me upon upgrade to xCode 4.3.1.

I found that editting the Run/Debug scheme and changing the Debugger setting in the Info tab from LLDB to GDB fixed the problem.

Comment: Cheers Matt, Dont get me started on LLDB! what a pile of crap, when hovering over objects it shown the value of the one directly above in code! GDB All the way and thats still crap!

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem.  If you explicitly declare the ivars in your h file, they should show up in the debugger as expected.

`@synthesize` will create the proper ivers for you, but it does not always make them accessible in the debugger endless you use the command line po to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

I have battled this issue for quite a while and I *finally* figured out the issue. I have several build configurations in my application (Debug, Release, UAT). When I hit 'Run' on my main scheme then I am using the 'UAT' configuration -- not 'Debug'. I realized that I was stripping debug symbols for my 'UAT' and 'Release' configurations. I simply modified my build settings to not strip debug symbols for the 'UAT' build configuration and voila, all my symbols are available again.

[image: Build Settings -- Strip Debug Symbols]

I am using XCode 4.5.1, but have seen this issue for quite a while on various projects. I assume that most of my projects use the 'Debug' build configuration by default and therefore were working fine. Only when I started getting fancy with my schemes and build configurations did I come across this issue.