# invalid summary problem while debugging in Xcode 

Tags: xcode, debugging

I have been trying to debug on Xcode and am facing the following problem:

Most of the times when I hover my mouse pointer over a variable to see its value I get invalid summary. However, in some cases i have a NSLog statement after that which prints the value of the same variable quite ok !

Can anyone kindly help me out with this weird problem ? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check out the quite similar question at SO which has a valid answer and workarounds: [xcode-4-debugging-shows-summary-unavailable-for-most-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301582/xcode-4-debugging-shows-summary-unavailable-for-most-objects)