# tableview reloadData doesn't work... - NSArray invalid summary

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray, datasource, uisplitviewcontroller

I have read a lot of posts about this topic, but i can't find an answer to fix my problem... For that reason I hope, you can help me:

I have got an iPad App with a SplitViewController Template. So the RootViewController is type of UITableViewController. My data is stored in two arrays, which are filled by a XMLParser (class SyncController). But the tableView doesn't show the data...

First my call of the parser in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.


    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    syncController = [[SyncController alloc] init];

    [syncController syncData];

    return YES;
}
```

That works. The SyncController is parsing the XML and at the End, I have got two instance variables (NSMutableArrays) of the SyncController filled with my data, I want to transfer to my RootViewController:

```
rootViewController.visitorNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.visitorNames];
rootViewController.visitorCompanies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.visitorCompanies];
[rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

reloadData seems to work:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"comp count: %u", [self.visitorCompanies count]);
return [self.visitorCompanies count]; }
```

The Console shows the right number of Elements...
But then, cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't called

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"testghjgjggjgjggjghjghjghjghjghjghjjhgghj");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


// Configure the cell.
cell.textLabel.text = [self.visitorCompanies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

There is no Console output.
So I've set a breakpoint at numberOfRowsInSection to look at the instance Variables

[Debug Output](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/146/debugo.jpg/)

They seem to be OK, but when you look at _dataSource of tableView, you see that there is an Invalid Summary...

I think that is the reason why my TableView doesn't work.

Info: If I don't use the SyncController and initialize the NSArrays with fixed values in RootViewController's viewDidLoad, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it works fine when you don't load the data via `SyncController`, I think the data source for the table view is working fine and the output produced by `NSLog()` suggests it too.

There must something wrong with `SyncController`. Your code example is :

```
rootViewController.visitorNames = [[NSArray alloc]
                                   initWithArray:self.visitorNames];
rootViewController.visitorCompanies = [[NSArray alloc]
                                       initWithArray:self.visitorCompanies];
[rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

This code takes place in `SyncController`, doesn't it ? And also :

```
// is self instance of SyncController, the app delegate ?
syncController = [[SyncController alloc] init];
// syncController.rootViewController = self.rootViewController ?
[syncController syncData];
```

Shouldn't you set this property before sync your data ?

Otherwise, if both your app delegate and your root view controller have properties named `visitorNames` and `visitorCompanies`, you should send your `syncController` object a reference to your app delegate, in order to fill the arrays with some data.

You may also consult this SO question & answers : [invalid summary problem while debugging in Xcode …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301582/xcode-4-debugging-shows-summary-unavailable-for-most-objects)
Hope this helps.

Comment: The missing property rootViewController was the solution. syncController.rootViewController = self.rootViewController <-- worked! Thank you!