# Debugging NSMutableArray gives out of scope message

Tags: objective-c

I declare an NSMutableArray in the header file and then initialize it and populate it as follows:

```
pointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:200];

[pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake( 167.9688, 285.1563)]];
[pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(   141.9678, 286.6211)]];
```

When I debug, I see the count of the pointArray is correct, but I can't look at the values of the individual CGPoint objects in the array.   I receive an Out of Scope  Summary Unavailable message from the debugger for each of the elements in the array.

Similar questions have been asked, but I have yet to find an answer that works in this case.  My apologies if I'm missing something.

Many thanks in advance.

Jon

Comment: You are not forgetting to take the pointValue of the NSValue objects?

Comment: Sounds as if it could be a problem with your debugger, specifically, the debug information. I'd clean, and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you have tried, but if you want for instance the first CGPoint you can use:

```
CGPoint p = [[pointArray objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
```

If you just want to look at them, printing the NSValues works fine:

```
    for (NSValue *v in pointArray)
        NSLog(@"%@", v);
```

**Edit:**

Sorry I might have misinterpreted your question. I don't use the debugger much, so I'm not the right person to answer this, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301582/xcode-4-debugging-shows-summary-unavailable-for-most-objects) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use GDB/LLDB console commands.

```
po pointArray 
po [pointArray objectAtIndex:0]
p (CGPoint) [[pointArray objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue]
```